# destroyed? returns nil instead of true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with `:allow_destroy => true`.

When deleting an object, I can see that the attribute `_destroy` is marked as `true`, but when I'm checking my object with `object.destroyed?`, I'm getting `nil` instead of `true`.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

> Now, when you add the _destroy key to the attributes hash, with a value that evaluates to true, you will destroy the associated model:
>
> member.avatar_attributes = { :id => '2', :_destroy => '1' }
> member.avatar.marked_for_destruction? # => true

`destroyed?` is here to check if the object is actually destroyed:

```
foo = Foo.first
foo.destroyed #=> false
foo.destroy
foo.destroyed? #=> true
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. My problem is that I'm deleting the value from the GUI and then the attribute is marked as "_destroy = true", my question is how I can find it under attributes? because when I try to check .destroyed? it returns nil

Comment: I'm getting exception on marked_for_destruction?. the method marked_for_destruction exists, but this method mark the object as destroy

Comment: what's your code? what's your rails version? see the doc I point to, the method is valid and makes what you expect

Comment: So it works too: http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/frames/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods I guess the issue lies somewhere else. what's your code?

Comment: it's not working on my rails version. the code is: self.values[1].destroyed?